# SVG: using getComputedTextLength to wrap text

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to wrap text by building up a text string, and using `getComputedTextLength` to find out when the text goes beyond the allowed width. However, I can't find a simple way to incrementally build up the text which will work with `getComputedTextLength`.

The general idea is:

```
  str = svgDocument.createTextNode(myText[word]); // first word on new line
  word++;
  obj = text.cloneNode(true);                     // new text element for this line
  obj.appendChild(str);
  svgDocument.documentElement.appendChild(obj);   // reqd for getComputedTextLength?
  for( ; word < myText.length; word++) {
     next_width = obj.getComputedTextLength();    // get current line width
     if(next_width >= extent)
        break;
     str += " ";                                  // add next word to the line
     str += myText[word];
     ...
  }
```

Can anyone tell me how to get this to work? Presumably `str` is copied rather than referenced in `obj`, but I've also tried putting `obj.removeChild(str)` and `obj.appendChild(str)` in the loop, but the `appendChild` crashes. I've also tried various combinations of moving around the `documentElement.appendChild`, and removing `obj` and re-appending it, and so on.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This should work:

```
    var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var width = 200;

    function init(evt)
    {
        if ( window.svgDocument == null ) {
            svgDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;
        }
        create_multiline("Whatever text you want here.");
    }

    function create_multiline(text) {
        var words = text.split(' ');                        
        var text_element = svgDocument.getElementById('multiline-text');
        var tspan_element = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "tspan");   // Create first tspan element
        var text_node = svgDocument.createTextNode(words[0]);           // Create text in tspan element

        tspan_element.appendChild(text_node);                           // Add tspan element to DOM
        text_element.appendChild(tspan_element);                        // Add text to tspan element

        for(var i=1; i<words.length; i++)
        {
            var len = tspan_element.firstChild.data.length;             // Find number of letters in string
            tspan_element.firstChild.data += " " + words[i];            // Add next word

            if (tspan_element.getComputedTextLength() > width)
            {
                tspan_element.firstChild.data = tspan_element.firstChild.data.slice(0, len);    // Remove added word

                var tspan_element = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "tspan");       // Create new tspan element
                tspan_element.setAttributeNS(null, "x", 10);
                tspan_element.setAttributeNS(null, "dy", 18);
                text_node = svgDocument.createTextNode(words[i]);
                tspan_element.appendChild(text_node);
                text_element.appendChild(tspan_element);
            }
        }


    }
]]>
</script>

<text x="10" y="50" id="multiline-text"> </text>
```

It works by adding tspan elements to the text element and then adding text to each of them.

The result is something like:

```
<text>
  <tspan>Whatever text</tspan>
  <tspan>you want here.</tspan>
</text>
```

In order for getComputerTextLength to work, you need to create the tspan (or text) element first and make sure it is in DOM. Also note that in order to add text to a tspan element, you need to use createTextNode() and append the result.

Comment: Hi Peter - thanks for the code. I was looking at my original code today and found that my basic problem was misunderstanding how to grow text in a text node. I got basic wrapping working with appendChild, but your tspan stuff looks good - I'll check it out. Thanks -Al

Comment: Cool - the tspans are useful as it means you can select the multiple lines of text at once.

Comment: Still helpful 7 years later, which I suppose is both good and bad!

Answer (score 4):

a wrapper function for overflowing text:

```
    function wrap() {
        var self = d3.select(this),
            textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength(),
            text = self.text();
        while (textLength > (width - 2 * padding) && text.length > 0) {
            text = text.slice(0, -1);
            self.text(text + '...');
            textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength();
        }
    }
```

usage:

```
text.append('tspan').text(function(d) { return d.name; }).each(wrap);
```

Comment: The OP does not appear to be using D3.

Comment: What does OP stand for?

Comment: Original Poster. What does D3 stand for? :)

Comment: D3 is JavaScript Library used to manipulate SVG. @RobertLongson, OP is not the only one who reads this. There is other people who needs solution for this and even more, some uses D3 as was in my case. Cheers!

Comment: Indeed which is why there's a d3 question about this very topic that you already attached this exact answer to! (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975440/add-ellipses-to-overflowing-text-in-svg)

Comment: Plain JS/DOM questions are STILL answered with jQuery snippets, yet the first question I see answered with d3.js is criticized. The answer from user2846569 is useful, because 1) d3 users interested in the topic may find his answer useful if they land on this answer first, 2) Core d3.js can be called the 'jQuery of SVG on steroids' - there is a large overlap between d3 users and those that need text truncation in SVG; 3) The OP or a reader might learn that what's a rather long, imperative, entangled code in the OP's question might be alternatively done with the more declarative d3 library.

Comment: Seems this requires that the SVG be visible: For example, if it's wrapped by something with `display:none;`, then `getComputedTextLength()` will return 0. This is my browser's behavior. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: might be so ... you can try hiding parent with "opacity: 0"