# D3.js implement ellipsis for axis labels SVG

Tags: css, d3.js, svg

Below is the code which is use to display the axis

```
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
.rangeRoundBands([0, totalWidth], barSpacing(optionsConfig.chart.barSpacing))
.domain(chartData.map(function(d) {
    return d[xValue];
}));
// Assign Scale to X Axis
xAxis.scale(xScale);
```

I want to show ellipsis on the x axis if the text is too long
I am referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975440/add-ellipses-to-overflowing-text-in-svg) link which has the below solution

```
function wrap() {
        var self = d3.select(this),
            textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength(),
            text = self.text();
        while (textLength > (width - 2 * padding) && text.length > 0) {
            text = text.slice(0, -1);
            self.text(text + '...');
            textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength();
        }
    } 
text.append('tspan').text(function(d) { return d.name; }).each(wrap);
```

but can any one help me how to implement the above code as I am new to d3.js or please suggest if this can be done with CSS or SVG approach.

Answer (score 7):

Try this way.

```
function wrap() {
  var self = d3.select(this),
    textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength(),
    text = self.text();
  while (textLength > (barWidth - 2 * padding) && text.length > 0) {
    text = text.slice(0, -1);
    self.text(text + '...');
    textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength();
  }
}

var padding = 0, barWidth = x.bandwidth();
var xAxis = d3.select(".axis--x"); //Selector should be the class given to the x axis

xAxis.selectAll(".tick")
  .selectAll("text")
  .html("")
  .append('tspan').text(function(d) {
    return d;
  }).each(wrap);
```

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
  y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
var data = [{
  "letter": "Abcdeafg Abcdeafg",
  "frequency": 0.08167
}, {
  "letter": "Bcdefagh Bcdefagh",
  "frequency": 0.01492
}, {
  "letter": "Cdefgahi Cdefgahi",
  "frequency": 0.02782
}, {
  "letter": "Defghaij Defghaij",
  "frequency": 0.04253
}, {
  "letter": "Efghaijk Efghaijk",
  "frequency": 0.12702
}, {
  "letter": "Fghijakl Fghijakl",
  "frequency": 0.02288
}, {
  "letter": "Ghijaklm Ghijaklm",
  "frequency": 0.02015
}, {
  "letter": "Hijklman Hijklman",
  "frequency": 0.06094
}, {
  "letter": "Ijklmnao Ijklmnao",
  "frequency": 0.06966
}, {
  "letter": "Jklmnoap Jklmnoap",
  "frequency": 0.00153
}, {
  "letter": "Klmnopqa Klmnopqa",
  "frequency": 0.00772
}, {
  "letter": "Lmnopqar Lmnopqar",
  "frequency": 0.04025
}, {
  "letter": "Mnopqrsa Mnopqrsa",
  "frequency": 0.02406
}, {
  "letter": "Nopqrsta Nopqrsta",
  "frequency": 0.06749
}, {
  "letter": "Opqrstua Opqrstua",
  "frequency": 0.07507
}, {
  "letter": "Pqrstuva Pqrstuva",
  "frequency": 0.01929
}, {
  "letter": "Qrstuvwa Qrstuvwa",
  "frequency": 0.00095
}, {
  "letter": "Rstuvwxya Rstuvwxya",
  "frequency": 0.05987
}];
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  return d;
});

x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.letter;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.frequency;
})]);

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10, "%"))
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", "0.71em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Frequency");

g.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.letter);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.frequency);
  })
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.frequency);
  });

function wrap() {
  var self = d3.select(this),
    textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength(),
    text = self.text();
  while (textLength > (barWidth - 2 * padding) && text.length > 0) {
    text = text.slice(0, -1);
    self.text(text + '...');
    textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength();
  }
}

var padding = 0, barWidth = x.bandwidth();
var xAxis = d3.select(".axis--x");

xAxis.selectAll(".tick")
  .selectAll("text")
  .html("")
  .append('tspan').text(function(d) {
    return d;
  }).each(wrap);
```

```css
.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}
.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}
.axis--x path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```