# How to break svg text with ellipsis using CSS?

Tags: css, svg, react-redux

I have to break text and put it in the rectangle box with ellipsis using css in react.Here is the svg text. How can i break svg text?

Here is my code:

```
<g transform="translate(-24.383999219712027,-8.991599712268808)">
   <rect x="0" y="0" width="48.767998439424055" height="17.983199424537617" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);stroke-width: 2px;fill: rgb(132, 225, 206);width: 103px;"></rect>
   <line x1="24.383999219712027" x2="24.383999219712027" y1="17.983199424537617" y2="26.974799136806425" style="stroke-width: 2px; fill: rgb(132, 225, 206);"></line>
   <line x1="17.06879945379842" x2="24.383999219712027" y1="21.579839309445138" y2="26.974799136806425" style="stroke-width: 2px; fill: rgb(132, 225, 206);"></line>
   <line x1="24.383999219712027" x2="31.699198985625635" y1="26.974799136806425" y2="21.579839309445138" style="stroke-width: 2px; fill: rgb(132, 225, 206);"></line>
   <text x="0" y="0" transform="translate(24.383999219712027, 8.991599712268808) scale(1,-1) rotate(0)" class="dotme" textOverflow="ellipsis" style="text-anchor: middle; font-size: 11px;">Rocky Arm Chair</text>
</g>
```

[image]

Comment: You may like to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975440/add-ellipses-to-overflowing-text-in-svg

Comment: @enxaneta I don't want to use js file

Comment: You have to use JS or use foreignObject to embed HTML text - SVG has little to no automatic text layout.