# How to add custom CSS to the layout's title?

Tags: angular, svg, plotly, plotly.js, angular14

I want to apply an ellipsis (`...`) on the layout's title and I'm not seeing anything to do it as per the [documentation](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/), unless I'm missing something.

I've tried adding some trivial custom CSS to the `gtitle`, highlighted element here to see if I could add the ellipsis this way.

[image]

As such:

```
.main-svg .infolayer .g-gtitle .gtitle {
    color: red !important;
}
```

And I'm not able to affect how the SVG is being rendered. I'm using plotly.js 2.18.1 in Angular 14.

Any ideas ?

Comment: `color` is not a valid attribute for `text` elements. It should be `fill`. Then the text color styling works. As far as showing ellipses goes I'm not sure that's possible with css alone, javascript might be needed.

Comment: Unfortunately `text-overflow: ellipsis` doesn't work for svg element. Instead, you could define a handler that will alter the <text> element as needed [using a wrapper function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27723752/2529954), and bind that handler to the 'plotly_relayout' event, ie. you can do the initial call and the binding with `Plotly.newPlot(...).then(function(gd){ handler(); gd.on('plotly_relayout', handler); });`