# SVG tspan find the pixel width and height

Tags: python, svg, height, width, tspan

I have some text paragraphs in Unicode.
What I want to do is to convert these paragraphs into images.
The process flow I chose was to convert the text into SVG first and then to png.

I am using python for this and do not use any third-party library at the moment as it's just simple text processing. (tspan element for each line)

The issue I face is some sentences are lengthy and go out of the view box.
Is there a way to figure out a consistent font size that would work for all paragraphs/images.?

Or in other words, is there a way to figure out the height and width in pixels of a given string?

Thanks

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046986/svg-using-getcomputedtextlength-to-wrap-text) is related but uses javascript instead.